# How do I store the data which is passed though the browser link in a mySQL database?

Tags: java, php, javascript, html, mysql

The code looks like this,

```
<form name="input" action="Sent.jsp" method="get">
<p><br>Reply:<br>
<textarea name="message3">Type Here</textarea>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"></p></form></td>
```

I want to capture the part of the link below in bold on my next page and store it in mySQL database

```
localhost:8080/WebContent/Sent.jsp?message=**Message+from+the+getter**
```

Comment: You need to open up Sent.jsp, and then handle the form data...

Comment: php, java, and javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are actually looking for `_GET['message3']`variable..

do something like that

```
    $message = _GET['message3'] ;
   if(isset($message){ 
    $sql = insert your $message variable in database here
    run the query
    }
     etc..
```

and you are done

I assume that you are learning over your localhost and you got the file Sent.jsp

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset('message'))
{
$message = $_GET[message];
//Now save $message variable to mySql
}
```

Comment: $variable = $_GET['message3'];

@Sebastjan

How you can GET message3, this is not POST form, just GET and you have only message variable?

Comment: AFAIK `'message'` is always set (as in, not `unset`). Did you mean `isset($_GET['message'])`?

Answer (score 0):

In your Sent.jsp file, you should use the check, if the variable was actually **set**, and if it is not **empty**

```
if(isset($_GET['message3']) && (!empty($_GET['message3']))
{
    $variable = $_GET['message3'];
    ...
```

and then store it into DB

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO tableName VALUES ('$variable')");
```